# PHP expression is true

Tags: php

I have the following PHP expression

```
($g == $key)
```

Values: `$g = objid` and `$key = 0`

If I dump the expression

```
var_dump(array($g == $key,$g, $key));
```

the result is

```
array(3) { [0]=> bool(true) [1]=> string(5) "objid" [2]=> int(0) }
```

Why is it showing `true`? I solve the problem using `===` in my expression but I would like to know why is this happening.

Comment: There's bound to be several dupes of this question, but as always locating them is hard. Google "PHP type juggling".

Comment: Long story short, it's a pitfall of PHP as a language. Better off always using the `===` operator because the `==` operator is highly inconsistent.

Comment: @eluong I believe it's an issue with any loosely typed language, not just PHP (Javascript for one). Best way to deal with it is to always use `===`. :)

Comment: You should either use the `===` comparison operator or the `strcmp()` family of functions, when comparing scalar values.

Comment: @General_Twyckenham Nope, I partially disagree. In JavaScript, `"string" == 0` will return `false` where in PHP, `"string" == 0` will return `true`. :'( why PHP

Comment: @eluong Wat lol. Never seen that one before. I retract my previous assertion. Friggin PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

> If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves
>   numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the
>   comparison performed numerically.

"objid " is not a valid number so it's converted to 0.

Answer (score 3):

PHP is converting your "objid" to an int, and is probably making it a `0`, so yeah, your "integerized string" is really equal to `0`.:

```
php > var_dump(' ' == 0, 'foobar' == 0, 'objid' == 0);
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(true)
```

Note that if your 'objid' string STARTED  with a number, then it would kinda/sorta/not-really work:

```
php > var_dump('a1b' == 0, '1ab' == 0);
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

And using the strict comparison `===` operator would also solve this. It compares values **AND** types. while `'foo' == 0` is true, `'foo' === 0` is false.

Answer (score 1):

The `===` is a type-safe equality operator - it makes sure that the objects you are comparing are of the same type.

`==` checks if the two objects have the same 'truthy' or 'falsey' value.
Ex:

```
0 == '0'
```

is true because '0' is considered a falsey value, but

```
0 === '0'
```

is false because one's an int and the other's a string